# Importing SCORM compliant Lesson (imsmanifest.xml)

Tags: scorm

I am developing a basic **LCMS (Learning Content Management System)** and I have to import a SCORM compliant lesson in my system for which I have to parse the **imsmanifest.xml** file and then import all the content basing upon the XML file.

Is there anybody who have done this task? Can you please guide me with sample code or a helpful link?

I am using VB.Net but even C# code will work for me.

Waiting for a quick and positive response
Thanks in Advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think XPath and Linq are the best technologies for you to parse the imsmanifest.xml to do this. You can also use System.IO namespace in C# to implement your project.

Comment: if you can give me some link or detailed answer? Whats the use of Linq? XPath and System.IO are mus obviously.

Comment: I have used personally but I don't find the link in between LINQ and my problem. Anyways..